# Why geolocation data in not returning from the helper to the template

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

Here is my Meteor code snippet - http://meteorpad.com/pad/sYoY8Xzjzd3sejFC4/Location

As you can see, in should write your current location in the `<p>` tag (you can check if `res[0].formatted_address` has any data by opening browser console - it should contain your current location).

But for some reason `<p>` remains empty.

Problems begin in the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` callback - if I modify the code, so the data is returned outside the callback - data goes to the `<p>`

Example:

```coffeescript
Template.location.helpers
  location: ->
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (position) ->
      if GoogleMaps.loaded()
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
        geocoder.geocode {'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)}, (res, status) ->
          console.log res[0].formatted_address
          res[0].formatted_address
    return 123
```

I tried to play with `Session` variables, and it worked - http://meteorpad.com/pad/nR4vgj7HqJvCdt3wE/Location-Session, but **why information from the callback is not going to the template, and how to fix it**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because the `res[0].formatted_address` is not reactive data like a Session variable.

and at the time the helpers return `res[0].formatted_address` to the template the value is ''.

You can check it like this.

```
var test = res[0].formatted_address
 if test != ''
  console.log 'hi iam a non reactive value and also im returning nothing'
 else
   console.log "yea my response is " + res[0].formatted_address
```

And ofc you will get the first console.log because at the moment you return the value to the template the value is `''`

The Session variable works, since the Session is a reactive data, and also the helper run assyncronus, so first the helper look for the `Session.get('location')` wich value is `''` **but some seconds leater** when the callback on the geolocation finish the value of the session is diferrent and the computation of the helper reruns the function and it return the value.

Comment: so, the best choice is to use `Session` for this?